# Как получить offsetLeft/offsetTop элемента <g id="iqaluit"> и <circle id="circle"> на странице?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Как в javascript получить offsetLeft/offsetTop элемента **<g id="iqaluit">** и **<circle id="circle">**.
Пробовал так: но выдаёт ошибку *TypeError: bar is null*

```
let bar = document.getElementById('iqaluit');
console.log(bar.offsetLeft, bar.offsetTop)
let circle = document.getElementById('circle');
console.log(circle.offsetLeft, circle.offsetTop)
```

```
<div class="section-map">
    <canvas class="svgfix__canvas" width="500" height="488"> </canvas>
    <svg id="MAP" data-name="MAP" data-province="MAP" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1100 1072.93">
        <g id="City_Labels_Canada" data-name="City Labels Canada">
            <g id="iqaluit" data-name="Iqaluit" data-province="nunavut" class="city nohover">
                <circle id="circle" cx="839.32" cy="390.34" r="3.1"></circle>
                <text x="847" y="394" data-name="Iqaluit" class="en de fr es">Iqaluit</text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('iqaluit');` а не `document.getElementById('#iqaluit');`

Comment: Спасибо, ступил. А `bar.offsetLeft` с не работает с канвасом ? просто пробую выдаёт undefined.

Comment: где в приведенном коде `canvas`? Вернее, как связано расположение `svg` элементов с `canvas`?

Comment: Наверное я не правильно сформулировал вопрос, мне нужен не сам canvas а ,offsetLeft элемента 
            `<g id="iqaluit">` или  элемента ` <circle cx="839.32" cy="390.34" r="3.1"></circle>`